# Where does docky store its configuration?

Tags: desktop, docky

I need to apply different profile of `docky`, for different desktop sessions, but I can't find where `docky` stores its configuration. I've tried `~/.docky` and `~/.config/docky` but these folders don't even exist.

Comment: I'm not using `docky` but it seems like it is using [gconf](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=GConf_Settings) – so they might reside under `~/.gconf/apps/docky/` or something similar. Am I correct?

Comment: @Sukminder ah, right, I've totally forget about this!

Answer (score 3):

As Sukminder points out, it's stored in gconf, here's my current solution,

e.g to set docky to show on left, auto hide and no panel mode:

```
gconftool-2 -s /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/Position -t string "Left"
gconftool-2 -s /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/Autohide -t string "Autohide"
gconftool-2 -s /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/PanelMode -t bool false
```